# FFMPEG | AVFilterGraph error WINDOWS and DEBIAN

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, debian

I trying to use FFMPEG for modify a vidéo. 
I have this command on this forum but I have some error

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"[0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:0:0[lt]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:ow:0[rt]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:0:oh[lb]; \
 [0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:ow:oh[rb]; \
 [lb][lt]hstack[top]; \
 [rt][rb]hstack[bottom]; \
 [top][bottom]vstack" \
-c:a copy output
```

Error windows : [AVFilterGraph @ 00000000035ecc20] No such filter: '\'

Error Debian  : [AVFilterGraph @ 0xe152ceab4e0] No such filter: ' '

Any solution to fix it ? Thx !

Answer (score -1):

I have the solution !
 Just remove all \ an all in single line !

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:0:0[lt]; [0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:ow:0[rt]; [0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:0:oh[lb]; [0:v]crop=iw/2:ih/2:ow:oh[rb]; [lb][lt]hstack[top]; [rt][rb]hstack[bottom]; [top][bottom]vstack" -c:a copy test.mp4
```